# How do you import a js file using {% load staticfiles%} in a base html template

Tags: javascript, html, django

Using Django {% load staticfiles %} I'm trying to load an app.js file in my base.html template.

I've seen several questions on StackOverflow about this and I also tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/javascript-tutorial/  but no of them actually helped with my issue.

It seems strange as well because on dev tools I see a 200 GET on the static/js/js.app and when I actually open the path the javascript is there.

Additionally, when I put the js code in a  at the end of the body it seems to work. But I want to load the js from a file.

Below is the latest that I've tried, but still no luck.

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load staticfiles %}

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'js/app.js' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


<body>

<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</div>


<!-- jquery -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- jquery -->
</body>
</html>
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Have you tried `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>` below your `</body>`?

Comment: Thanks @Paolo it works now. Would you mind explaining why the js file loads in this case?

Comment: Because that is how you refer to JS files from HTML. You don't use `link`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following script after the **body** tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

**Why?** When loading JavaScript files, it tends to fall under one of two cases.

1. The Javascript file contains functions which are needed **while** the page is loading **OR**
2. The Javascript file contains functions which should be used **after** the page is loading.

**Conclusion** 
If the JS file contains functions referencing HTML elements then you should put it after the `body` tag so the page's DOM elements can finish loading first before the script. Else, putting it in the `head` works as well.

**P.S** - You should also consider performance, as there is a difference in that aspect when importing **JS files** in the `head` and after the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>` below my `</body>` fixed the problem I had with the js file not loading.